# How do I construct a dictionary of dictionary of dictionaries?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I was going through some basic gene encoding techniques and came across a problem:

My dictionary should look something like :

```
codon_dict= {
    "A": {
        "A": {
            "A": 0.0,
            "T": 0.0,
            "G": 0.0,
            "C": 0.0
        },
        "T": {
            "A": 0.0,
            "T": 0.0,
            "G": 0.0,
            "C": 0.0
        },
        "G": {
            "A": 0.0,
            "T": 0.0,
            "G": 0.0,
            "C": 0.0
        },
        "C": {
            "A": 0.0,
            "T": 0.0,
            "G": 0.0,
            "C": 0.0
        }
    },
    "T": {
        "A": {
            "A": 0.0,
            "T": 0.0,
            "G": 0.0,
            "C": 0.0
        },
        "T": {
            "A": 0.0,
            "T": 0.0,
            "G": 0.0,
            "C": 0.0
        },
        "G": {
            "A": 0.0,
            "T": 0.0,
            "G": 0.0,
            "C": 0.0
        },
        "C": {
            "A": 0.0,
            "T": 0.0,
            "G": 0.0,
            "C": 0.0
        }
    },
    "G": {
        "A": {
            "A": 0.0,
            "T": 0.0,
            "G": 0.0,
            "C": 0.0
        },
        "T": {
            "A": 0.0,
            "T": 0.0,
            "G": 0.0,
            "C": 0.0
        },
        "G": {
            "A": 0.0,
            "T": 0.0,
            "G": 0.0,
            "C": 0.0
        },
        "C": {
            "A": 0.0,
            "T": 0.0,
            "G": 0.0,
            "C": 0.0
        }
    },
    "C": {
        "A": {
            "A": 0.0,
            "T": 0.0,
            "G": 0.0,
            "C": 0.0
        },
        "T": {
            "A": 0.0,
            "T": 0.0,
            "G": 0.0,
            "C": 0.0
        },
        "G": {
            "A": 0.0,
            "T": 0.0,
            "G": 0.0,
            "C": 0.0
        },
        "C": {
            "A": 0.0,
            "T": 0.0,
            "G": 0.0,
            "C": 0.0
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of hard coding this, is there any way to construct it from lists? or iterate through a for loop and construct the same?

that is code_dict["A"]["A"]["A"] should return me 0.0

Comment: What operation would you perform on your four bases to obtain all possible combinations of the four (hint: look in the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module)? Do that, and then set the value of that nested key to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```py
from itertools import product

s = "ATGC"

out = {}
for x, y, z in product(s, repeat=3):
    out.setdefault(x, {}).setdefault(y, {})[z] = 0.0

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "A": {
        "A": {"A": 0.0, "T": 0.0, "G": 0.0, "C": 0.0},
        "T": {"A": 0.0, "T": 0.0, "G": 0.0, "C": 0.0},
        "G": {"A": 0.0, "T": 0.0, "G": 0.0, "C": 0.0},
        "C": {"A": 0.0, "T": 0.0, "G": 0.0, "C": 0.0},
    },
    "T": {
        "A": {"A": 0.0, "T": 0.0, "G": 0.0, "C": 0.0},
        "T": {"A": 0.0, "T": 0.0, "G": 0.0, "C": 0.0},
        "G": {"A": 0.0, "T": 0.0, "G": 0.0, "C": 0.0},
        "C": {"A": 0.0, "T": 0.0, "G": 0.0, "C": 0.0},
    },
    "G": {
        "A": {"A": 0.0, "T": 0.0, "G": 0.0, "C": 0.0},
        "T": {"A": 0.0, "T": 0.0, "G": 0.0, "C": 0.0},
        "G": {"A": 0.0, "T": 0.0, "G": 0.0, "C": 0.0},
        "C": {"A": 0.0, "T": 0.0, "G": 0.0, "C": 0.0},
    },
    "C": {
        "A": {"A": 0.0, "T": 0.0, "G": 0.0, "C": 0.0},
        "T": {"A": 0.0, "T": 0.0, "G": 0.0, "C": 0.0},
        "G": {"A": 0.0, "T": 0.0, "G": 0.0, "C": 0.0},
        "C": {"A": 0.0, "T": 0.0, "G": 0.0, "C": 0.0},
    },
}
```